# Issues with routing URLs with more than one static part

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

Is it only my particular problem, but every time I try to map a URL with more than one static part say:

```
POST /search/apps SomeController.someMethod
```

I get a 404 error.

if I change the URL to `/search/apps/` (with a trailing slash)
it works.

Is this set by default? I am using PF 1.2.5

Comment: I would expect it to be the other way around, according to the [routes docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/routes#syntax).
Have you already tried to define the route as `/search/apps`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, all the routes have a preceding slash